# The fastest and easiest way to intersect all lists from two different objects

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class Info
{
    public List<string> Projects { get; set; }
    public List<string> Schools { get; set; }
    public List<string> Locations { get; set; }
    public List<string> Interests { get; set; }
    public List<string> Hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

To intersect 2 lists, you can just do this: `list1.Select(a => a.Projects).Intersect(list2.Select(b => b.Projects));`

But what if you want to have maybe an third object with the common strings let's say from the first two objects?

Comment: What prevents you from continue doing the Intersect as you move further from 1st to last list, you will get the final solution. `ProjectList.Intersect(SchoolList).Intersect(LocationList).Intersect(InterestList).Intersect(HobbyList)`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj nothing prevents me, but i thought maybe with onliner it can be done?

Comment: Wouldn't that also be one liner

Comment: @MrinalKamboj , uhm yeah, didn't see it like that :)

Comment: @SGN Cool, this would be the simplest in my view, just fetch the final result in a List

Comment: @MrinalKamboj thanks for clarifying

Comment: See msdn samples : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution I can think of is `Cascading Intersection`:

```
var result = Projects.Intersect(Schools)
                     .Intersect(Locations)
                     .In‌​tersect(Interests​)
                     .Intersect(Hobbies)
                     .ToList();
```